# In software testing, particularly blackbox test. How do you deal with cases with unknown expected result?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, pytest

I was given a task to do a blackbox testing on a command line app. Say the app is supposed to take an integer within certain range and give some output.

I wasn't given any other information apart from this. So then when input is float or an out-of-range integer, the input is not valid but the app could also return something.

So the question I have is: how should I handle those cases. I probably shouldn't assume it should return an exception or something because it wasn't clear when I received the features of what this app is supposed to do. My test (I use Pytest in Python) also can't do assertion as I don't know the expected result.

I would like to keep a record file just with a list of all unspecified cases and their raw outputs for the developer to review. Is that the right way to go?

Many thanks

Comment: If your task is to test the specified functionality, then certainly you have to get the correct specification, including how the app shall behave on all sorts of input. If some of it is not specified intentionally, the output will be undefined and you can't test these cases.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, can I interpret as they are uninterested in the output if the input is not within their specification. Hence I don't need to test the float and out-of-range cases in this particular test? Shall I still report in my testplan mentioning the cases I didn't test?

Comment: Well, you have to ask them that. And yes, even if they say they are uninterested I would mention it in the test plan for future consideration, but that is just my opinion, not a guideline :)

Comment: _Say the app is supposed to take an integer within certain range and give some output._ If this is the only specification you've got, this is also the only thing you can test: execute the program with an integer in certain range and check whether some output received. Writng missing specification is not the responsibility of the tester (but it often is made to one). You can indeed extract the specs from the existing code and get the PO's approval on them, then write the tests, but not the other way around.

Comment: Of course you can test something like the app doesn't raise an exception on invalid input etc, but this is still testing against the common sense, not app's specs.